# How can I initialize an object in the constructor of another class?

Tags: c++

in my project , I have classes which are connected with each other. if a class has an object of another class as an attribute , how can I initialize it when I write the constructor ?

I tried to write as below , but I had an error. Note that class Date has a constructor which is Date(). if I write dueDate = 0 , it will give an error.

also in Task(string n , Date d) , can I initialize the other attributes or only the parameters ?

```
class Task
{
   private:
   int id;
   string name;
   Date dueDate;
   string status;
   bool urgent;

   public:
   Task();
   Task(string n, Date d);
};

Task::Task(){
   id = 0;
   name = "*";
   dueDate = 0;
   status = "New";
   urgent = false;
}
Task::Task(string n, Date d){
   name = n;
   dueDate = d;
}
```

Comment: Could you include the error? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Date` offers a constructor for `int`, the correct solution here it to switch to [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) rather than *assigning* in the body of the constructor (which means the members are all default initialized, then reassigned). Just move all your assignments to initialization like so:

```
Task::Task() : id(0), name("*"), dueDate(0), status("New"), urgent(false) {}
Task::Task(string n, Date d) : name(std::move(n)), dueDate(std::move(d)) {}
```

This changes your use case to only needing a constructor (explicit or otherwise) for `Date` that accepts `int` (or a pointer, where `0` will be interpreted as the `NULL` pointer), rather than needing to handle assignment from `0` to an existing instance.

It's also much more efficient to do it this way; instead of five default constructions and five reassignments, you just do five direct constructions with the intended arguments from the get-go. In the case of the constructor accepting a `string` and `Date`, using `std::move` means the objects are only constructed from scratch once (when the caller calls the constructor), then move-construction is used to hollow out the arguments and move their internals to the data members instead of copy-constructing only to throw away the source anyway.

If you must assign to an existing `Date` and it can't implicitly convert an `int` for you, if you have a move or copy assignment operator for `Date`, you can reuse it. The most minimal fix to your code in that case would be to just replace:

```
dueDate = 0;
```

with:

```
dueDate = Date(0);  // Explicitly construct a `Date` then copy/move assign to dueDate
```

but again, using initializer lists is the way to go here.

Note: If `Date`'s only constructor takes no arguments, as in your example:

```
Date::Date()
{
   day = 0;
   month = 0;
}
```

you don't need to explicitly initialize or assign it if you just want it to have the default value. Data members are automatically initialized with their default constructors before the body of constructor for the class containing them is executed; `Date()` happens automatically. `dueDate = Date();` would be extra pointless in that case, since it would just be reassigning `dueDate` to a fresh empty `Date` when it already *was* an empty `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

First, create a pointer:

```
class Task
{
   private:
   Date* dueDate;

   //...
};

Task::Task(){
   // ...
   dueDate = new Date(0);
}
Task::~Task(){
   // This way requires a destructor though
   delete dueDate;
}
```

Option 2: you can overload the assignment operator:

```
class Date
{
   public:
   void operator=(int i);
};

Date::operator=(int i) {
   // implement construction
}
```

Then, in task:

```
Task::Task(){
   // ...
   dueDate = 0;
}
```

These are the two options I know of. In C++, there is no way to call the constructor directly as a member variable. You must use as a pointer, or implement the assignment operator.

**Edit:** Shout-out to Shadow Ranger who pointed out in the comments that C++14 and higher has a solution which doesn't require a destructor:

```
class Task
{
   private:
   std::unique_ptr<Date> dueDate;

   //...
};

Task::Task(){
   // ...
   dueDate = std::make_unique<Date>(0);
}
```

Comment: Note: You wouldn't necessarily need a destructor even if you decided you needed to use a pointer. Just make the member `std::unique_ptr<Date> dueDate;` rather than `Date *dueDate;`, and you can do (on C++14 and higher) `dueDate = std::make_unique<Date>(0);` Following the Rule of Zero means you don't need to define a destructor; the implicitly defined destructor will call the destructor for `unique_ptr` and do the cleanup for you. Modern C++ code almost never needs to use either `new` or `delete`.

Comment: Ah, good point. I'm not terribly familiar with C++14 or higher (still on C++ 11), which is why I didn't catch that. Feel free to suggest an edit, or I can edit when I get a chance.

Comment: Only real change on C++11 is that you'd use `std::unique_ptr<Date>(new Date(0))` instead of `std::make_unique<Date>(0)`, as `std::make_unique` didn't exist. It means you have the mild ugliness of using `new` at all, but in this case it should be otherwise identical.

Comment: @ShadowRanger do I need a destructor in the C++11 version too, since I am using new?

Comment: No. Once it's wrapped in `std::unique_ptr`, it's uniquely owned by it; the `std::unique_ptr` destructor takes care of it.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Task
{
   private:
   int id;
   string name;
   Date *dueDate;
   string status;
   bool urgent;

   public:
   Task();
   Task(string n, Date d);
};

Task::Task(){
   id = 0;
   name = "*";
   dueDate = new Date(0);
   status = "New";
   urgent = false;
}
Task::Task(string n, Date d){
   name = n;
   dueDate = &d;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the problem, and it adds dynamic memory management (implemented incorrectly in one way or another, since one use case is explicitly `new`ing it, the other it taking the address of a temporary, and in neither case did you define a destructor to free the memory). Pointers aren't needed here.

Comment: If you absolutely must use dynamically allocated memory you really should be using a smart pointer like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`  -- but in this case you can just use dueDate as a member variable.